# How come this `e.currentTarget` is null in debouncing function?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, debouncing

I made a debounce function in Vanilla JS to understand how debouncing function works.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<div>
  <input id="text" type="text" />
</div>
```

```js
// index.js
const textLog = (e) => {
  console.log('--textLog start--');
  console.log(e.target);
  console.log(e.currentTarget); // 1. e.currentTarget is null at this point
  console.log('--textLog end--');
};

const debounce = (func, wait) => {
  let timeOutId;
  return (arg) => {
    console.log('target', arg.target);
    console.log('currentTarget', arg.currentTarget); // 2. arg.currentTarget exists at this point
    if (timeOutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeOutId);
    }

    timeOutId = setTimeout(() => {
      func.call(null, arg);
    }, wait);
  };
};

const debounceLogging = debounce(textLog, 1000);
const input = document.getElementById('text');
input.addEventListener('input', debounceLogging);
```

This is just logging the enterd value of the input after user stopped typing for a second (1000 ms).

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mcneev?file=index.js

In `textLog()`, I initially used e.currentTarget.value to get the enterd value to the input, but it threw an error saying `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`.
Then I replaced `currentTarget` with `target` and it worked as I intended.

What I know about a difference between `target` and `currentTarget` is the element that is reffereing.
However, to me, this error happend because of other cause.

- I checked inside the function returned from `debounce()`, `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` both have values inside of them.
- But inside the `textLog()` called inside of the returned function, `e.target` is not null, but `e.currentTarget` is null.

Could anyone tell me what caused thie error or why this error happend?
Thank you

Comment: The `event.currentTarget` property is set to `null` when the event finishes propagating.
In your `debounce()` , you are calling the `textLog` function ***asynchronously*** using `setTimeout`. This means that by the time `textLog` is executed, the event propagation is already finished, and `event.currentTarget` is set to `null`.